# RevMob - NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, revmob

I have been searching for an answer for 3 days now but cannot seem to find one. Im not an expert coder but have some sort of knowledge in the field.

I am trying to incorporate RevMob AD Network into my application but I keep getting this error when I call the `revmob.ShowFullscreen();` in `Start()`.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object RevMobSampleAppCSharp.Start () (at Assets/Scripts RevMobSampleAppCSharp.cs:36)

Answer (score 1):

Just create an instance of revmob by the sounds of it...

```
revmob myRevmob = new revmob();
```

Comment: Thank you! I have figured out the solution but now my banner AD isn't clickable for some reason. Fullscreen AD's work fine but banner AD's no. Any suggestions? Or should I post my manifest file and GameObject script?